# Nashorn in Java 8 maven project

Tags: java, maven, java-8, java-11, nashorn

I am facing a problem where the nashorn JavaScript engine does not work in my maven project.
The following code works in a standalone java file when I use both java 8 and java 11,

```
ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
if (engine == null)
    System.out.println("The engine is null.");
```

But when the same code is used in my maven project it only works with java 11. When I use java 8 in the maven project, `engine` is null. I printed out the existing engines and their aliases and I see nashorn and the JavaScript alias. This was working before and I don't think it is breaking because of a change in my project. I also do not have a dependency on nashorn in my maven project (as it should exist in java 8?). Any ideas?

Note: I am using java 1.8 (or Java 8), the problem disappears when I use Java 1.11 (or Java 11).

Comment: Yes, I printed out the available engines and their names. I did get nashorn and JavaScript. However, when I do `manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript")` I get `null`. I reinstalled java and also ran this in multiple different systems, but I get the same error.

Comment: Did you try a step debug? The `getEngineByName` method just iterates over the available engines and their names (literally, instead of a simple `contains` call), so it’s weird to see a difference between your iteration and their iteration.

Comment: Are you sue you are using Java 11 and not 16 or 17? Since Java 16 Nashorn is no longer part of Java.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue.

Java 1.8, Maven 3.8

When i run tests via `mvn test` - nashorn javascript engine is not available and i get error `Can't find scripting engine for 'javascript': scriptEngine is null`.
At the same time, when the application or junit test run via idea - everything is OK.

In my case problem was in the surefire plugin configuration:

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                    <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                    <reportsDirectory>${junit.utReportFolder}</reportsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Problem is forkCount = 0. If remove param forkCound (go to default value) - nashorn engine becomes available.